Use DAX to find manager name and manager hire date
I have an employee table that displays the employee number, name, and manager's employee number. I'm trying to create a query that displays the emp name, emp#, manager name and mgr hiredate in Power BI using Dax.
The table looks like this:
EMPNO ENAME  JOB       MGR  HIREDATE  SAL COMM DEPTNO 
7839  KING   PRESIDENT -    17-NOV-81 5000 -   10 
7698  BLAKE  MANAGER   7839 01-MAY-81 2850 -   30 
7782  CLARK  MANAGER   7839 09-JUN-81 2450 -   10 
7566  JONES  MANAGER   7839 02-APR-81 2975 -   20 
7654  MARTIN SALESMAN  7698 28-SEP-81 1250 1400 30 
7499  ALLEN  SALESMAN  7698 20-FEB-81 1600 300 30 
7844  TURNER SALESMAN  7698 08-SEP-81 1500 0   30 
7900  JAMES  CLERK     7698 03-DEC-81 950  -   30 
7521  WARD   SALESMAN  7698 22-FEB-81 1250 500 30 
7902  FORD   ANALYST   7566 03-DEC-81 3000 -   20 

I tried merge as new option and tried this but it didnt work. Can someone help?

You can use a calculated column to get the MGR NAME and MGR HIREDATE. For this, you can try something like this:
MGR NAME = 
VAR __mgr = 'Table'[MGR] // Insert your table name instead of 'Table'
RETURN
CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[ENAME]), FILTER('Table',__mgr = 'Table'[EMPNO]))

This calculated column uses the VAR __mgr = 'Table'[MGR] to store the current row context and then uses the same row context to get the data that you need.
Hope it helps.

In your case you need 2 calculated columns and I recommend that you model your data in a more appropriate way :
ManagerName = 
IF (
    ISBLANK(Employees[MGR ]),
    BLANK(),
    LOOKUPVALUE(Employees[ENAME], Employees[EMPNO], Employees[MGR ])
)

Then :
ManagerHireDate = 
IF (
    ISBLANK(Employees[MGR ]),
    BLANK(),
    LOOKUPVALUE(Employees[HIREDATE],Employees[EMPNO],Employees[MGR])
)


